# Mapping Stored Procedures in Onion Architecture

Tags: stored-procedures, service, dependency-injection, onion-architecture

I'm writing automation to black box test applications. The applications will not work with mock data, so I'll need to grab or create real data from the database using pre-written stored procedures that I have no control over. There are a lot of stored procedures.
I'm also using onion architecture and DI to abstract away the CRUD-ing of my entities, be it through stored procedures or API's. Right now I have 5 layers: entities, repository interfaces, repositories, service interfaces, and services.

Lets say in my test I want to create an entity. I would use a call to an `IEntityService`, `service.Create(entity)`. This service would then make use of some of the stored procedures, such as is_entity_valid, and create_entity to validate and create the entity. Again since I am merely testing, I do not control the business logic or how it is implemented, I just need to be able access the things that do implement it.

My question is this: How do I fit those stored procedures into my layers? Should they go in a repo? A service? Somewhere else?

Right now I'm thinking of dumping related sp's into classes in the repo layer, then calling them from whatever repo implementations need them. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Setting up test data isn't really part of what DDD is concerned about.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't sound a lot like DDD. You're talking about infrastructure and architectures, and haven't once mentioned the domain, UL, or BCs, which is not a common form of discussion in DDD. Further, you'd end up putting the SPs in repos of the appropriate bounded context and exposing them as a service. So, they'd go everywhere they need to go. I'm voting to close as unclear, because within the context you've given it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve with conflicting views of the world.

Comment: @EngineerDollery apologies, this is my first attempt at DDD. The lack of clarity in my writing is a result of a lack of clarity in my understanding. Could you help me resolve some of those conflicting views you mention?

Comment: My mistake. Your question isn't about DDD and the DDD tag has been removed by a subsequent reviewer.